# Firestore - accessing transactional/nested data in security rules

Tags: transactions, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm hoping someone can help me on this one. I really love the new Firestore beta but the lack of simulator/debugger at the moment has left me struggling with a problem.

I have a collection of scenarios which can be up-voted or down-voted. I want to restrict anyone malicious up-voting/down-voting something multiple times so I also have a sub-collection of votes for the scenario. These are just documents keyed by userId that contain a hash like

```
{
  up: true,
  down, false
}
```

[image]

In order to write these multiple items (i.e. scenario document and vote sub-collection) in one request I use a transaction.

The problem I'm having is that I want to validate that when "points" is updated by a user it **must** be accompanied by a vote document that sets up/down to true, depending on the points and whether a vote already exists for a user.

In the security rules, how is it possible to read if the vote sub-collection data exits in the request when I'm validating at the scenario document level (or visa-versa)? It's my understanding that "request.resource.data" only allows you to see the data for the current document level being written to (I could be wrong here but there's no easy way to check and there's nothing in the documentation). Here's an example of my security rules so far:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Scenarios
    match /scenarios/{scenarioId} {
        allow read;
      // Only allow write if all of these are true
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId &&
                                            // points    
                                    request.resource.data.points == 0;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null &&
                       (
                        request.resource.data.points >= (resource.data.points - 2) ||
                        request.resource.data.points <= (resource.data.points + 2)
                       )
                       // TODO: Only allow write to points IF accompanied by a "votes" document for that userId
      // Votes
      match /votes/{voterId} {
        allow write: if voterId == request.auth.uid;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the current +/- 2 points validation is because if a user has already down-voted a scenario they can increment by two points by performing an up-vote (removal of the existing down-vote + the new up-vote). This validation will become more sophisticated once I know how to access the "vote" details :)

Comment: Anyone at all??

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I reported it to the Firebase team but never got a response

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing this problem, you may try using the exists() function in the security rules:

```
allow update: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/scenarios/$(scenarios)/votes/$(request.auth.uid));
```

Alternatively, you may want to consider storing the list of uids in an array to check in the rules in the document itself if the quantity is not going to reach the firestore document quota:

```
//your document structure
points: 0
someData: xx
voted: [id1, id2, id3 .. n]

//in the rules
allow update: if !(request.auth.uid in resource.data.voted);
```

with this approach, you will need to have a background worker to add the userid to the array, and prevent user writes to the voted array using:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.voted == resource.data.voted;
```

Comment: I think the problem with using exists is 1. that's for checking existing data (but I need to validate data in the request), 2. exists will perform another "read" and I want to minimise my read usage. It would be great to be able to check the data in the transaction (the way Firebase allows). Storing an array in the document itself could work but again, this means I need to use a cloud function and additional writes every time someone performs a vote. It's going to chew through my quota of writes/cloud function invocations and feels a little hacky. Thanks for your suggestions